# What is the Java class for a Tomcat session?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, jvm, jmap

I made a **JVM heap dump** of my **tomcat** server with `jmap`, and I'd like to figure out what is the size of all the sessions in memory.

As such I would like to know **what type of object** I should be looking for to estimate the **sessions** size.

Thank you

Comment: `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` and the [javadoc for it is here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).  Note that it's an interface, but there's a [tomcat interface that extends it `org.apache.catalina.Session`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/Session.html).  I would look for all the classes that implement the Catalina Session interface; [`org.apache.catalina.cluster.session.DeltaSession`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/cluster/session/DeltaSession.html), [`org.apache.catalina.cluster.session.ReplicatedSession`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/cluster/session/ReplicatedSession.html), and [`org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.html).

I'm sure there are a few confounding variables which might make session tracking not 100% correlate to memory usage, but at least it's a start.

Comment: +1: Not sure I like the wording on this (specifically calling them subclasses instead of implementing classes), but you mention the same classes I was going to point out.

Comment: Yes ! Worked with `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession`, thanks (for now I guess my server don't use the other types of sessions)

Comment: @R. Bemrose, yes, I've fixed the wording (and added fully qualified class names, and included more links back to Tomcat 5.5 documentation).  Sorry for the odd wording, but it's part of my write / read / edit / rewrite life-cycle.

Comment: @Matthieu, I am sure that 95% of us use the `StandardSession` exclusively, but the others were right there in the javadoc, so I included them (just in case).

Answer (score 0):

javax.servlet.http.HttpSession

Comment: [`HttpSession`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) is an interface, not a class.

Comment: This class is never used in my project, I've got no results with that.

Answer (score 0):

**org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession**, gave me an idea about tomcat sessions, when analyzing a heapdump.